# Disable the Nightperson perk's nightvision in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I am currently playing Fallout 4 vanilla on PC.  I have just gotten the nightperson perk rank 2.

The added perception is nice but the nightvision is giving me trouble.

I can actually see better without it and it is now hurting my eyes.  I am a stealth build and I like to snipe and the nightvision is making the sniping worse.

How do you disable nightvision?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to several sources, it is not possible to turn it off without mods or console. So I'll describe those two.

*The two methods mentionned here are two among many. You may find other sources doing the same job.*

### Console method ([source here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136914594917/))

All commands are to be typed in without first and last quotation marks **only**.

1. Open the console with grave/tilde (left of your keyboard).
2. If you want to remove/add a perk type "player.removeperk code" or "player.addperk code". If you want to remove night person rank 2 specifically, type: "**player.removeperk 001d2495**".
3. If you want to remove other perks, or if you want more info on other codes, you can type in "help "name of perk" 4". It will give you all the console codes for the night person perks.

Concerning achievements, a Steam user says you can use the console as much as you want, nothing is blocked when using it.

### Mod method ([source here](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/5866/))

Simply follow the instructions given on source page (link above) to load the mod into your game. This mod removes only the Night Vision effect, and keeps all other bonuses this perk may give you. There is no info whether this mod blocks achievements or not.

Comment: I will try this later after work.  It sucks to lose a perk though.

Comment: @fja3omega so did it worked as intended? The mod method suggests that only the effect is removed, the perk and all bonuses are still effective.

Comment: The perk removal worked.  Just sad about the loss of increased perception.  The mod will be next on my list.